# MemSQL stored procedure

Tags: singlestore

We would love to use MemSQL, and we have been internally evaluating it's performance. We've reached the limit of performance from plain SQL and now one thing we would need is the to create embedded functions (A la PL/SQL) that would perform optimised numerical calculations.

An example use case would be storing a series of numbers as an array (or in MYSQL speech, a LONGBLOB) and multiplying each value by a value in another array (a vector dot product), we would prefer this to be in C++ (should not be a problem as you compile the SQL to c++) potentially using a GPU.

This is possible in several other distributed DBs (postgresXL for example), and we've started looking at how MEMSQL loads in the .so's it generates, and think it would be possible to hack this mechanism to do what we want, but is there any official plan to support this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a user-defined function in MemSQL 6. It supports user-defined functions compiled to machine code. See http://docs.memsql.com/v6.0-beta/docs/procedural-sql-reference

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL supports stored procedures, user-defined functions and custom aggregations now since version 6.0 released at the end of 2017.

Here's the documentation for the MemSQL procedural language features: https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/reference/sql-reference/procedural-sql-reference/procedural-sql-reference/